# creating block matrix in maple

Tags: maple

I would like to create a matrix built from particular submatrices. In particular, let's say $A,B,C,D$ are $n \times n$ matrices (take $n=2$ if you want). I want to define
$$ M = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} A & B \ C & D \end{array} \right] $$
I don't mind if it gets "flattened". Actually, the real problem has $n^2$ blocks of $n \times n$ matrices each of which is either the zero matrix or one of three standard blocks. But, I ask the question for this simple block because I think I can understand the larger problem once I get this. Should I just use "block" of the old linalg package?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can just pretend the entries are matrices and it interprets it as you would likely desire. I'm very happy about all this:

[image: It's just what it should be. Thanks to Bill.]

Comment: Yes, that is why the `stackmatrix`, `blockmatrix`, and `augment` routines of the now deprecated `linalg` package are not reproduced in the newer `LinearAlgebra` package. The `Matrix` constructor or its shorthand angle-bracket syntax does job. Another way, efficient for larger examples and float[8] datatype Matrices, is to form an empty Matrix and then use `ArrayTools:-BlockCopy`.

Comment: @acer Thanks for the comment, do you have any advice on symbolic computation where the matrices are filled with unknown functions or even differential operators? We've toyed with the Equal command, but I'm not confident on how to go forward.